# SVN: get file properties from post-commit hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Is it possible to get file properties from post-commit hook?

I want to check all changed files, if one or more of them have my specific property, I want to perform some action.

```
svn propget my:property file.txt
```

^ this reads properties only from local working copy, but i don't have it in the env where hook is executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use a hook, you should use the `svnlook` command and not the `svn` command.

```
TXN=$1
REPOS=$2
SVNLOOK="/usr/bin/svnlook"

"$SVNLOOK" pget -t $TXN $REPOS my:property /path/in/repository
```

You can get a list of files that have been changed via the `svnlook changed` command:

```
/usr/bin/svnlook changed -t $TXN
```

This will provide you with the change type (U = Updated, D = Deleted, M = Modified, R = Replaced) and the name of the file. You can use that file name with the `svnlook pget` command to look at the property.

Maybe something like this:

```
$SVNLOOK changed -t $TXN | while read changeType fileName
do
    $SVNLOOK plist -t $TXN -v $REPOS $fileName
done
```

One of the problems with shell is that you can't do loops in loops very easily. For example, it would be nice if I could do something with `$SVNLOOK plist`, but I am already piping STDOUT to STDIN, so any output from `svnlook plist` will affect my outer loop. You can do all sorts of weird stuff to use other file descriptors, but it's simply easier to use Python or Perl.

You also really can't change anything about the commit. You can't change a file or a file property. The only thing you can change is a revision property like `svn:log`, and even that's not recommended.

Not sure what you had in mind, but be careful. Also understand that anything that can take too long will delay the user's commit as they wait for your post-commit script to run. I've seen people attempt to compile and run unit tests in Subversion hooks. In that case, you're better off using a continuous build system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to do post commit processing.

You can take a look at my [svn-watcher-hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Watcher-Hook) to see how it's done. This is a Perl script, but it's not all that complicated, and I try to explain everything I do. It shouldn't be too hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also will look at Jenkins, because I've already have some actions in hooks, and adding this may slow svn down